# Linq remove multiple objects

Tags: c#, linq

I could able to search for each item in the list and if that item exists, then I remove it from the list as follows.

However, instead of writing that many lines of code, I just wonder there is a better way doing it.

```
var math = subclasses.Classes.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(Constants.Classes.Math.ToString())).FirstOrDefault();
if (math != null) subclasses.Classes.Remove(math);

var chem= subclasses.Classes.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(Constants.Classes.Chem.ToString())).FirstOrDefault();
if (chem!= null) subclasses.Classes.Remove(chem);

var physics= subclasses.Classes.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(Constants.Classes.Physics.ToString())).FirstOrDefault();
if (physics!= null) subclasses.Classes.Remove(physics);
```

Comment: Try where and take all except chem math and physics

Comment: @Dolev Could you please illustrate with an example?

Comment: Why FirstOrDefault()? Are there more than one that will meet the condition, and you only want to kill the first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove them all without LINQ if `Classes` is a `List<>`:

```
subclasses.Classes.RemoveAll(x => x.Id.Equals(Constants.Classes.Math.ToString())
                               || x.Id.Equals(Constants.Classes.Chem.ToString())
                               || x.Id.Equals(Constants.Classes.Physics.ToString()));
```

Comment: Assuming `Classes` is a `List`, I suppose.

Comment: @kenneth yeah you're right. Ooooopsy, I missed that part where OP mentioned "list". On mobile, so can't really see much ;)

Answer (score 1):

2 steps:

1. Write an overloaded version of `Remove()` that takes a List to remove. (Assuming the original Remove is your own implementation, and is a method of your class named Classes)
2. Use `Array.Contains()` to get the list to remove

Something like this (on mobile, so...):

```
string [] mathChemPhy = new string []
{
    Constants.Classes.Math.ToString(),
    Constants.Classes.Chem.ToString(),
    Constants.Classes.Physics.ToString()
};

var itemsToRemove = subclasses.Classes.Where(x => mathChemPhy.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
subclasses.Classes.Remove(itemsToRemove); // overloaded version of Remove that takes a list
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Except extension method:

```
var exceptions = subclasses.Classes.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(Constants.Classes.Math.ToString() 
    || x.Id.Equals(Constants.Classes.Chem.ToString() 
    || x.Id.Equals(Constants.Classes.Physics.ToString());
var result = subclasses.Classes.Except(exceptions);
```